# Dump ambassador/envoy 5xx payload

Tags: kubernetes, gateway, envoyproxy, ambassador

i have a microservices architecture deployed. I have several worker, and ambassador as a gateway.  My problem is i got error log http 5xx, but i don't know what is the payload of the request. So i can't reproduce the error.

Is there any way to dump payload at ambassador/envoy when there is 5xx request?

Comment: Did you try to use `tcpdump` to see the incoming requests? Something like `tcpdump -aA -s0 port <app_port>`

Comment: i have a lot of container, i dont know which one to tcpdump. And my container doesnt have tcpdump

Comment: You could start to find from where your request is incoming, for example, are you using ingress ? Try to log on the ingress pod and run the tcpdump. Please give more details about your issue, like the resquest is GET, POST? From where the request is coming. The error 5xx is when you send a POST with some especific data? Please include theses details in your original question.

Comment: hmm, interesting. But my docker image doesnt have tcpdump pre-install..